# HTML Signatures not displaying correctly on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have created a signature template using basic html tables and inline styles. This template displays perfectly on pretty much every email client including Android. The massive problem is that most of our partners/members/staff use iPhones! (shocking I know!) would anyone know how to stop the iPhone from displaying my tables like this.

This is my code

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/dnut.png" />
    </td>

    <td style="padding:5px">
    <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/AOPwording.png" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color:#1294c2;">
                Daryl Liney
                </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:8pt; color:#4a4949;">
                IT Support
                </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </td>

    <td>

        <table style="padding-left:5px;"  style="border:thin black solid">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Location.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                2 Woodbridge Street, London, EC1R 0DG
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Phone.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                020 7549 ****
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Phone.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                020 7549 ****
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Print.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                020 7251 ****
                </td>
            </tr>    

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Message.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                <a href="mailto:*********@aop.org.uk" style="color:#4a4949;">**********@aop.org.uk</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="https://asite.where.img.comes/Globe.png" />
                </td>

                <td style="font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:#4a4949;">
                <a href="http://www.aop.org.uk" style="color:#4a4949;">www.aop.org.uk</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </td>
</tr>
```

This is how the iphone displays the image
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kHPv.png)

This is how it should look
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7e17.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow best practices while designing HTML templates as there are many blogs available to guide which things to do or don't do while designing templates.

Error in your template is:

If your text is in a container with a width set to less than that of your text, it might wrap poorly on this device. Here I am putting a sample template so that you can have basic idea how to create templates.

Here is a Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> 
      <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
      <title>Simples-Minimalistic Responsive Template</title>

      <style type="text/css">
         /* Client-specific Styles */
         #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
         .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/
         #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
         img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
         a img {border:none;}
         .image_fix {display:block;}
         p {margin: 0px 0px !important;}
         table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
         table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
         a {color: #0a8cce;text-decoration: none;text-decoration:none!important;}
         /*STYLES*/
         table[class=full] { width: 100%; clear: both; }
         /*IPAD STYLES*/
         @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #0a8cce; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #0a8cce !important;
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 440px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 420px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}
         img[class=colimg2] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}


         }
         /*IPHONE STYLES*/
         @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #0a8cce; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #0a8cce !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 360px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 360px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         img[class=colimg2] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         td[class=mobile-hide]{display:none!important;}
         td[class="padding-bottom25"]{padding-bottom:25px!important;}

         }
         @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #0a8cce; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #0a8cce !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 325px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 325px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         img[class=colimg2] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         td[class=mobile-hide]{display:none!important;}
         td[class="padding-bottom25"]{padding-bottom:25px!important;}

         }
         @media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #0a8cce; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }
         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #0a8cce !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         img[class=colimg2] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         td[class=mobile-hide]{display:none!important;}
         td[class="padding-bottom25"]{padding-bottom:25px!important;}

         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
<!-- Start of preheader -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="preheader" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <table width="" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #808080" st-content="viewonline" class="mobile-hide">
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of preheader -->       
<!-- Start of header -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="header">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <!-- logo -->
                                    <table width="140" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="169" height="45" align="left">
                                                <div class="imgpop">
                                                   <a target="_blank" href="#">
                                                   heading
                                                   </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of logo -->
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="2columns">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <!-- start of left column -->
                                    <table width="290" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <!-- Spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- Spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                <!-- start of text content table -->
                                                <table width="290" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <!-- image -->
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td width="100%" height="1"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; color: #000; text-align:center; line-height: 36px;" st-title="fulltext-title">
                                                            Your Heading
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <!-- Content -->
                                                      <!-- end of Content -->
                                                      <!-- end of content -->
                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- end of text content table -->
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of left column -->
                                    <!-- start of right column -->
                                    <table width="290" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <!-- Spacing -->
                                          <!-- Spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                <!-- start of text content table -->
                                                <table width="290" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <!-- image -->
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td width="290" height="160" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                                                            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1UcNyUp_I2JbSRX5G0S-UNdEk3Jv2cwUvsEZAWfs0sd_xKbM7K7A7UVSe" width="200" height="200"alt="" border="0"  style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" class="colimg2">
                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <!-- end of Content -->
                                                      <!-- end of content -->
                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- end of text content table -->
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of right column -->
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- end of 2 columns -->

<!-- Start Full Text -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="full-text">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <!-- Title -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #808080; font-weight: bold; text-align:left; line-height: 30px;" st-content="fulltext-content">
                                                <span id="userNameSpan">Hello, Customer</span>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of Title -->
                                          <!-- spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of spacing -->
                                          <!-- content -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #808080; text-align:left; line-height: 18px;" st-content="fulltext-content">
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris fringilla tellus quis lacus tempus malesuada. Mauris consectetur bibendum tellus sed viverra. Aenean scelerisque lacus quis odio interdum, nec hendrerit nibh dapibus. Morbi leo ex, feugiat at elementum eget, ultricies sit amet nibh. Vivamus tristique feugiat condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of content -->
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="30" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Start of seperator -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="seperator">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" height="30" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="550" align="center" height="1" bgcolor="#d1d1d1" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" height="30" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

You need to write media queries also to support your template in mobile devies.

Happy Coding!

Comment: For more info: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/7_tips_on_designing_and_developing_emails_for_the_iphone

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the Objective C iOS coding.It will work for you.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad     
{
  NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",htmlData]; //htmlData is you are getting html response to this.It may be string or array means you are getting html response to String htmlData or array htmlData.
  [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}

//WebView Delegate Method
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
   CGRect frame = webView.frame;
   frame.size.height = height;
   webview.frame = frame;
}
```

In above viewDidLoad method you load the html data to webView.So it automatically brings to your expected form.
In above WebView Delegate Method, you can set the html data content height to webView height.